# how to remove clipping from audio using sox?

Tags: linux, audio, sox

i am looking to use -G or -v to limit a track's volume to avoid clip.

```
sox audio1.wav -G audio2.wav
```

or

```
sox audio1.wav -n stat -v
1.000

sox -v 1.000 audio1.wav audio2.wav
```

but nothing works as aspected.

Comment: How do you want to avoid clip? If a signal clips, there's nothing to rescue

Comment: To clarify what (i think) slhck is saying: if the signal was clipping at the time of recording, then there is no way to remove the clipping. Reducing the volume will only lower the volume of the clipped "plateau"

Comment: @horatio Exactly what I was getting at!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the track was recorded and clipped when recorded, you cannot "fix" the clip by reducing the volume. The recorded signal will still exhibit the clip, but at a reduced volume.